# Android service notification and contentIntent

Tags: android, service, notifications

First of all the context. 
I have an app uploading multiple files to a server.
I actually have : 
 -a service uploading with an FTP connection.
 -a notification beeing updated by the service (progressbar)
 -an activity with the details of every file uploading "ProgressActivity"

In the current configuration. The activity starts the service and then receive information about the connection progress. Communication is done with an implementation of ServiceConnection.

As soon as I need the user to be able to navigate arround the application during the upload process, I want the user to be able to access the ProgressActivity simply on clicking the notification.

I tried to ad an intent calling the ProgressAvtivity on the contentIntent but as soon as it's another instance of the Acitvity, the binding is not anymore viable.

We also need to keep in mind that the user should be able to have multiple FTP services running at once.

Any guess on how to achieve this ?

If more details required feel free to ask.

Comment: Just a note to the note. considering the questions I posted and the answers I had previously, I did accept every answer that solved my problem.

Comment: What binding is not available in the new instance of an Activity? Also, just curious, why would you want to use more than one Service?

Comment: When I start the service I se bindservice and add a reference to the activity as a listener. When I restart this activity, I of course don't receive updates from the activity.
I don't know if multiple service should be the right thing to do but the user should be able to lauch multiple uploads.

Comment: you should pastebin your bindservice code.  And you should probably just use one service with multiple threads

Comment: Using multiple thread shaould be a good idea. Here is the code of the connection I use : http://pastebin.com/YL5fzNLX.